# Равномерное распределение данных по таблицам

Tags: sql, sybase

Попалось мне тестовое задание

---

Имеется 2 таблицы следующего содержания:
Таблица А:

```
Референс договора на кредитную карту REP_REF (тип поля текстовый)
Бранч (код отделения) договора ECA_BRNM (тип поля текстовый)
Логин сотрудника, за которым закреплен договор LDAP_EXPERT (тип поля текстовый)
```

Таблица Б:

```
Логин сотрудника LDAP_LOGIN (тип поля текстовый)
Бранч (код отделения) сотрудника ECA_BRNM (тип поля текстовый)
Код бизнеса сотрудника BUS_BUS (тип поля числовой)
Код должности сотрудника POSIT_POS (тип поля текстовый)
```

Задача:
Отобрать все договора, которые закреплены за сотрудником, работающем на бранче, который не совпадает с бранчем договора или если указанного сотрудника нет в таблице Б. Найти в таблице Б сотрудника который работает на бранче договора.
------- в котором есть одно из  условий

4)      если на бранче найдено несколько сотрудников указанных выше бизнесов, то распределить договора равномерно между ними

Пробую использовать

```
COUNT(DISTINCT LDAP_EXPERT) AS exp_cnt  FROM A
into #EXP_COUNT
IF  (#EXP_COUNT.exp_cnt ) > 1
NTILE(2) OVER(PARTITION BY  REP_REF ORDER BY LDAP_EXPERT) gr
FROM BUS_BUS ORDER BY  *********??.
```

но мне кажется, что это полная муть. Как правильно использовать для этого  условия эту функцию ?
или можно  обойтись простыми вещами

по логике, должно  работать так

нужно посчитать кол-во договоров и кол-во сотрудников, между к-ыми их нужно распределить
далее, пронумеровать договора подряд (от 1 и до кол-ва сотрудников)
и пронумеровать сотрудников
далее к таблице с договорами сджойнить таблицу с сотрудниками по условию, что номер у договора совпадает с номером у сотрудника

помогите составить запрос

Comment: Вам IF count() вообще не нужен. Если запрос сможет распределить договора на N сотрудников, то и на N=1 сотрудника он все договора отлично повесит. И старайтесь писать примеры более развернуто, без слов "select" и точек с запятой далеко не сразу понимаешь, что это куски отдельных инструкций TSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не понял как пользоваться NTILE, точнее как правильно передать ему нужное количество, полученное в том же запросе. И решил взять записи с одинаковыми остатками от деления порядкового номера записи в разрезе договоров и в разрезе сотрудников на количество сотрудников. Так же из вопроса не ясно какое поле является первичным ключем в таблице договоров, написал ID, замените на нужные в выборке поля.

```
select id,LDAP_LOGIN
  from
  (
   select A.id,B.LDAP_LOGIN,
          row_number() over(partition by A.id order by B.LDAP_LOGIN) rn,
          row_number() over(partition by B.LDAP_LOGIN order by A.id) rn2,
          count(distinct B.LDAP_LOGIN) over() cnt
     from A, B
    where A.ECA_BRNM=B.ECA_BRNM
      and not exists(select 1 from B as B1
                      where B1.LDAP_LOGIN=A.LDAP_LOGIN
                        and B1.ECA_BRNM=A.ECA_BRNM
                    )
  )
where mod(rn2,cnt)=mod(rn,cnt)
```

`not exists` в запросе, что бы взять те договора, для которых назначены неверные сотрудники. Что сказано у вас в начале задачи, но вы это опускаете в итоговой формулировке как бы вы это сделали.

Что в вопросе означает "указанных выше бизнесов" совершенно не ясно, потому как выше ничего подобного не сказано. Если надо добавите необходимые дополнительные условия.

P.S. запрос писался для Oracle, все используемые функции есть в Sybase. Может потребоваться написать что то внутри пустого `over()` который для Oracle означает окно размером во всю выборку.

Comment: я еще попробовал вот так 
SELECT t1.ECA_BRNM, t1.LDAP_LOGIN, t2.REP_REF
  INTO #RESULT
  FROM #BRANCH_SOTR_NUMBERED    t1
  LEFT JOIN #BRANCH_REF_NUMBERED   t2 ON t2.ECA_BRNM = t1.ECA_BRNM
                                     AND t2.REF_NUMBER = t1.SOTR_NUMBER
     ;
Ваш код сильно  изящен для меня, я человек без  опыта работы) Жаль, нету доступа к базе, что-бы затестить , а про not exists пока не понял.

Comment: @tews Ну такой запрос даст записи с тем же отделом и неким номером  и плюс к ним зачем то выберет сотрудников для которых вообще не нашлось договоров. У вас в Sybase вот эти таблицы с # - это некие временные таблицы которые вы предыдущими запросами заполнили ?

Comment: @tews А что до not exists, по русски если его прочитать выйдет типа "такие записи в договорах для которых не существует записи в таблице сотрудников с таким же логином и отделом", т.е. эквивалентно вашему "все договора, которые закреплены за сотрудником, работающем на бранче, который не совпадает с бранчем договора или если указанного сотрудника нет в таблице Б"

Comment: Тут, видимо, нельзя говорить спасибо.Я пока не разобрался , как вам можно лайк поставить , вы очень выручили

Comment: Да, временные таблицы и есть